# Run custom javascript when external list table loaded

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, external-list

Is there any way to run custom javascript after table with external custom list is loaded on page? The external list table is loaded on page with some delay and I would like to modify its content using javascript.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to post the question here - it's no good linking somewhere else because the link may disappear at some point in the future and render the question useless. We will close the question for now, but please flag for moderator attention when you have improved the question and we will be able to re-open it for you. Many thanks.

Comment: Thank you for editing. I'm not sure just deleting the link helps - I was hoping you would expand on the problem in the question. I've re-opened it anyway and I hope there is enough there to get you some answers.